# Error while Upgrading the Database Schema for Sitecore Publishing Service

Tags: publishing-service

We are on Sitecore 9.0.1, Publishing Service 3.1.3 and Azure PaaS.

We are facing few issues in content publishing. During debugging we found out in Publishing Service the Link Database is set to Core DB which should be Web DB.

When we updated the `sc.publishing.xml` to change the Link DB we were seeing the following exception:

```
 [Error] [ "DATABASE NAME" ] - Looking for data schema version : 1. Found: 0
```

When we are trying to upgrade the schema using the following command:

```
Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host schema downgrade –-force
```

It is throwing the exception below. Did anyone experienced this?

```
[20:47:24 INF] Schema Downgrade
[20:47:27 INF] Downgrading all databases to version [ 0 ]

[20:47:27 ERR] There was an error dropping Schema Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.Common.Sql.Schema for DATABASE NAME
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find the type 'Publishing_Data_FieldDataType'. Either it does not exist or you do not have the necessary permission.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<ExecuteImplAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.SchemaInstaller.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.AdoNet.NoRetryConnectionBehaviour.<ExecuteAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseConnection`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.SchemaInstaller.<Apply>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Data.SchemaInstaller.<RunDowngradeScripts>d__15.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:b2a5a362-a528-4aac-9105-90b442e16551
Error Number:218,State:1,Class:16
ClientConnectionId before routing:23b74648-7a64-45f0-8951-adf28e841232
Routing Destination:cf2894f5e316.tr257.southcentralus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11050
```

Answer (score 4):

It ended up with the Permission issue with SQL User defined per database in connection string. It need to be SQL admin user not the database user which are created during installation.

To run the Upgrade or Downgrade command, please make sure the `sc.publishing.xml` is using the SQL Admin credentials. Once commands are successfully executed, you can switch them back to the database specific users.

Comment: I hope future versions of Sitecore Publish Service will enforce providing a connection string on the command line or similar, since a connection string in `sc.publishing.xml` should never have such high privileges as needed to perform a schema change. Right now it's a bit too easy to forget a connection string with admin privileges in the config after installing & configuring SPS